# Favicon and bootstrap images not correct with IntelliJ/Tomcat

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tomcat, intellij-idea, twitter-bootstrap-3, intellij-13

I have some weird problem with my website I'm developing. Since a couple of days now, I saw that my favicon and some other images were broken.

My favicon looks like this:
[image: Favicon image]

If I use the bootstrap 3 glyphicons, I get something like this:
[image: Normal image] (background is in color, it's the white square that's the trouble).

I have no idea why this is, but it came all of a sudden (probably changed something I can't remember anymore). I thought it could maybe be a temporay problem, and it would maybe go back to the original image after some time. So far it hasn't.
Now the most disturbing thing is that the code does work on the server. So when I push my code to the repo and redeploy, the website deploys correctly. All the images are working: both the favicon and the glyphicons.

So I think the code is correct (otherwise it wouldn't work on the server). That's the reason why I didn't paste any code; but if it could be the code, I would be happy to share. So then I guess the problem is maybe my local testing environment? I'm now using IntelliJ 13.1.4 on Linux, in combination with a local Tomcat 7.0.54 instance. I'm not using the latest versions, but I didn't update just before the problem occured.

I already tried to use a different local port, to circumvent the caching of my browser. But that didn't help. Also trying it in different browsers doesn't help. So caching isn't the issue in my opinion.

If I try it in Chrome, I only see the glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff and glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf files in the Network tab of the Developer tools. These are only of the 2 of the 4 files that are in the fonts directory of Bootstrap 3 (also a .svg and .eot file). Should these files also load in Google Chrome? Or is this normal?

When I build my project with maven, copy the generated war to my Tomcat webapps folder, the website appears to be like it should (images working). So it has to do something with the temporary folder that is used by IntelliJ to show the website.

If anybody could help to fix this problem, I would appreciate it. Ok, it's not really a major issue because it is working on the production server; but it's rather annoying I can't fully test the site on my local machine.

Comment: Check in what `Content-type` these images are served, maybe this has changed for whatever reason.

Comment: How can I check that? If I check in my file browser (Thunar), I get an "unknown" in the "Type" column for some files. But then those shouldn't work when I manually place the WAR in the Tomcat folder? Because then I can see the images correctly.

Comment: Try this with Google Chrome. Press F12, open network tab and reload the site. This should show you request properties.

Comment: The type of my favicon is image/x-icon, so that sounds good. The Bootstrap 3 images, I can't really find out because they use a larger image. The .woff and .ttf  give the following types, respectively: x-font-woff and x-font-ttf. Weirdly, I would expect to see the .svg in Chrome, but I don't see it there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I was using a maven filter to parse the files. And during that parsing, the files got distorted a little. Disabling the filter on my local machine solved the problem.